# How do I approach fixing a layout constraint error? Trying to update ClockAnimation for Auto Layout

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I found this sweet clock on github, https://github.com/DuncanMC/ClockAnimation

I emailed the dude that wrote it and he wasn't a fan of auto layout. With auto layout on this clock is all over the place, which obviously isn't going to work out too well whilst trying to hit multiple iPhone models.

I'm using this clock as a background view in my project, and if I turn auto layout on the hands completely disappear. In my storyboard they are centered in the view. That's all I know unfortunately. Here's the error that logs out when it's run:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x10932ac40 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x109327af0(22)]>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x10932ac90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x109327af0(250)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x10932ac90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x109327af0(250)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-06-20 15:50:25.116 Project Manager[1547:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x10932ad80 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x109328e50(22)]>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x10932add0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x109328e50(250)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x10932add0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x109328e50(250)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-06-20 15:50:25.117 Project Manager[1547:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x10932aa90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x109329a30(22)]>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x10932aae0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x109329a30(250)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x10932aae0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x109329a30(250)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I'm totally in the dark on where to start, whether it's the visual layout in storyboards, the size inspector in storyboards, or in WTClockView.m, so any light shed on the matter is much appreciated. I'll be sure and post the auto layout version for all to use after we get this working.

Comment: I cloned that project.  I turned on auto layout in the storyboard.  I ran it.  It looked fine.  I clicked on the view controller in the storyboard and then chose Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Add Missing Constraints in View Controller.  I ran it again.  It still looked fine.  What did you do differently?

Comment: I should clarify that I did all this in Xcode 6b2.

Comment: I tried that and here's what happened: http://screencast.com/t/L9iw5yvN00

Comment: To answer your main question, what I did is: 1. copied the hands out of Images.xcassets into the corresponding Images.xcassets in my project
2. drag and dropped the clock view right onto my view controller's view
3. imported WTClockView.h
4. started the clock in code

Comment: This was in the current Xcode so I don't know if the beta has an extra voodoo magic or not.